# How to Optimize Nginx & PHP FPM based on server specification

Tags: php, nginx

my server always hit 502 bad gateway where the load average is low. I have no idea what the causes of it. Been trying to figure out setting Nginx and PHP FPM but getting the same result.

Server Specification

2x E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz [16 cores]
32 GB RAM

Here is my nginx settings

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 2500;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid     /var/run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/modsecurity*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;


http {
    include    mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/web.access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush  on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_requests 200;
    keepalive_timeout  130;

    #gzip  on;
    
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    
    # If your domain names are long, increase this parameter.
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    
    # To hide the version number in headers
    server_tokens off;
    
    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Here is the php fpm conf

```
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 0
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 20
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10
request_terminate_timeout = 120s
```

Can you provide regarding the calculation? and explain it so we can learn it how to set it properly

Comment: If there is a calculation, no one can do it but you. We do not know what your app requires in terms of CPU, memory, or time, nor what your request rate might be like. There is no one magic formula that will tell you what those settings should be. The first step is to set up system monitoring so you know what the conditions were when your app misbehaved, and then you can make decisions from there and see the effect.

Comment: can you provide tool to monitor each php request [RAM]?